# How to filter by date in DB2 from Oracle via DB Link

Tags: database, oracle, db2

I need to run a query on a DB2 database from Oracle via a DB Link.

This query needs to filter the results by date, but I want this to be done remotely, I don't want all the data coming back through the DB Link and then the filtering done locally - this is causing major performance problems.

But I am not sure how to accomplish this because if I just do the filtering straight forward then Oracle wants to filter it locally.

Example:

```
Select * From DB2_TABLE@DB2_LINK.WORLD
WHERE DATE1 >= SYSDATE -1
AND DATE1 <= SYSDATE
-- AND assume whole bunch of other filtering being done
```

If I run it like that, I can see via the plan that Oracle is pulling all the data and then filtering it locally afterwards. There must be a way to 'remote' that filtering over to the DB2 side. Any ideas?

Comment: MS SQL Server uses **openquery** to do this.  But a quick search failed to turn up the equivalent in for Oracle.

Comment: Side note: Don't use an inclusive upper-bound, you must use an exclusive (`<`) one.  Especially on Oracle, where `DATE` has time attached.

Comment: Interesting side note - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a filtered view in the DB2 database, then query that view from Oracle?

Comment: I wish I could but it's a system we have no control over and takes months for that team to do anything.